# Using Google Analytics UTM parameters with Twitter

Tags: twitter, google-analytics

I'm starting to use Google Analytics for real-world QR code advertisements, and as far as I can tell, I should be putting `?utm_source=STORE&utm_medium=POSTER&utm_campaign=1` or (with specific parameters) in each QR code URL I'm tracking.  So far it works just like this for URLs I own.

But when I use `https://twitter.com/MYTWITTERACCOUNT/?utm_source=STORE&utm_medium=POSTER&utm_campaign=1`, Twitter gives me a 404.

So how do I use UTM parameters with Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't allow you to do this do this for privacy reasons (among others). You'll need to run the request through a intermediate service that does log the information into Google Analytics (or other logging system) for you (similar to what URL shortners do) then redirect the user to Twitter.

Comment: I was originally trying to put `https://twitter.com/MYTWITTERACCOUNT/?utm_source=STORE&utm_medium=POSTER&utm_campaign=1` through goo.gl to get a short url to make into a QR code.  Are you saying I will have to use a different URL shortener that somehow logs to GA WITHOUT using utm parameters in a URL?

Comment: If so, can you give an example of a URL shortener that does this?

Comment: @themirror You'd need to find a service that accepts the UTM parameters, and is able to log that against your analytics account, then forwards onto `http://twitter.com/twitter`. I don't know of any services that provide that type of service out of the box. You maybe looking at writing something custom to support that.

Comment: @themirror No doubt, but it will be tricky since Google Analytics is very client side based. Searching around at URL services is probably your best bet, or writing it yourself.